# NHibernate PostUpdate Event Listener Runs Before Database Row Update

Tags: nhibernate

I'm in a situation where I fire off messages to RabbitMQ after certain NHibernate entities are updated.  Ideally, I'd like the consumers of those messages to see the version of the entity that reflects the update.

I decided to try raising the events by implementing the `IPostUpdateEventListener`, thinking that this would ensure that the consumers saw an up-to-date row, **but I seem to have a race condition where the message consumers sometimes load the entity before its row has been updated in the database**.

[The documentation on the `IPostUpdateEventListener` interface](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Event/IPostUpdateEventListener.cs) seems to indicate that the code runs *after* the datastore is updated, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I pulled up Sql Server Management Studio, NhProf, and did some debugging.  I verified by stepping through the code that my `OnPostUpdate` code runs *before* the entity's row in the database is updated.

I'm updating the entity in a transaction, with code something like this...

```
using(var transaction = session.BeginTransaction()) {
    session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Am I misunderstanding or misusing the `IPostUpdateEventListener`?  Is there another "hook" I can use to enqueue messages, ensuring that an update has occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using transactions then I use the following events to do this:

`post-commit-insert`
`post-commit-update`
`post-commit-delete`

Config example:

```
<listener class="yournamespace.youreventhandler, yournamespace" type="post-commit-insert" />
<listener class="yournamespace.youreventhandler, yournamespace" type="post-commit-update" />
<listener class="yournamespace.youreventhandler, yournamespace" type="post-commit-delete" />
```